# Wildfly 10 per-deployment logging log4j.xml ignored for WAR project

Tags: java, maven, logging, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm having problems getting the per-deployment logging in my Wildfly 10 application to work correctly.

I put the log4j.xml file in WEB-INF/classes :

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="300MB" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="file" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/rtc-notify.log" />

    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Archive file to roll to @ midnight (yyyy-MM-dd) with compression -->
        <param name="FileNamePattern"
            value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/rtc-notify.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

But the file is never created and no logs appear anywhere, even in the main server.log file.

I haven't changed the `add-logging-api-dependencies` nor the `use-deployment-logging-config` so Wildfly should accept this.

Maybe it has something to do with the dependencies in pom.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. 
  and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See 
  the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors. 
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not 
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy 
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myapp.notify</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp-notify</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>WildFly Quickstarts: myapp-notify</name>
  <description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>

  <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
      message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
      resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
      tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom>8.2.0.Final</version.jboss.bom>

    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-analyzers</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>


      <!-- <dependency> -->
      <!-- <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
      <!-- <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> -->
      <!-- <version>1.7.10</version> -->
      <!-- </dependency> -->

      <!-- <dependency> -->
      <!-- <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
      <!-- <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> -->
      <!-- <version>1.7.10</version> -->
      <!-- </dependency> -->

      <!-- <dependency> -->
      <!-- <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
      <!-- <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> -->
      <!-- <version>1.7.10</version> -->
      <!-- </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-jms</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
      <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.3.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-json-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-websocket-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
      of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
      JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
      as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
      in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
      JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
      given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
      <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <filename>${project.artifactId}.war</filename>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <home>${wildfly-home}</home>
          <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
          <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
          <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
          <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I'm using 8.2.0.Final for jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate as the BOM is not prepared for Wildfly 10. Should I manually change all the dependencies here and not rely on the bom?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the FileAppender I was trying to use. The RollingFileAppender with daily compression is not available in the basic log4j package. The apache-log4j-extras package is required but it doesn't come with Wildfly 10. On our previous setup with Wildfly 8 we manually added this module but it had been forgotten during migration.

Comment: It's available in log4j, just not in the `org.apache.log4j.rolling` package. It works if you use `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`. FWIW I've filed a JIRA to fix the error of not printing the error messages from log4j https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1656

Comment: I was noy aware of that. Thanks for the tip about the basic log4j library. It's better if we can avoid using extra modules. And yes, some kind of error message would be extremely useful.

Comment: However, as far as I can see in the documentation, the TimeBasedRollingPolicy class is not available in the basic log4j package and DailyRollingFileAppender is said to have some issues and thus use of extras is recommended anyway. In that case, I think we'll stick with using extras as it's already configured and working.

Comment: FWIW there is a [`DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) in the base log4j library.

Comment: "DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss. The log4j extras companion includes alternatives which should be considered for new deployments and which are discussed in the documentation for org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender." from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html